# how to merge arrays from 2 different arrays

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

this is an image from the API that returns the test results before and after each other. 
Initially when the user has not entered the test result, the array `result = null`, After the user enters, the array will have the same result as the image below: 
my problem is after user input test, and then we update field `result_template` can be add or remove `subjects` so how do i merge `subjects` if use edit again `result_template`,
If there are new `subjects` but no scores are available, the default is set = 0 
You can watch the video for better understanding: [link](https://ttprivatenew.s3.amazonaws.com/pulse/tikho900-gmail/attachments/20795407/TinyTake10-01-2023-09-01-04.mp4) 
desired result: [image](https://tikho900-gmail.tinytake.com/media/13d5029?filename=1673317288269_TinyTake10-01-2023-09-14-49_638089140836175915.png&sub_type=thumbnail_preview&type=attachment&width=1200&height=642)
[image: my result]

here is my code:

```js
 const { data } = await this.$store.dispatch(
    `${UserGeneral.STORE_ADMIN_USER_KEY}/getDetailSchoolResults`,
     this.$route.params.id
);
const formData = data.data;
      if (formData.result) {
        const listResultTemplate = formData.result.result.map((item) => {
          let data = {
            title: item.title,
            subjects: [],
            files: [],
          };

          item.files.forEach((file) => {
            data.files.push(file);
          });

          item.subjects.forEach((subject) => {
            data.subjects.push({
              name: subject.name,
              scores: {
                total_score: subject.scores.total_score,
                medium_score: subject.scores.medium_score,
                private_score: subject.scores.private_score,
              },
            });
          });
          return data;
        });

        this.result = listResultTemplate;
      } else {
        const listResultTemplate = formData.result_template.result_template.map(
          (item) => {
            let data = {
              title: item.title,
              subjects: [],
              files: [],
            };

            item.subjects.forEach((subject) => {
              data.subjects.push({
                name: subject,
                scores: {
                  total_score: 0,
                  medium_score: 0,
                  private_score: 0,
                },
              });
            });
            return data;
          }
        );

        this.result = listResultTemplate;
      }
```

thanks for your help !

Comment: could you be more specific about what you trying to do here, i have some trouble with understand your question.

Comment: I can summarize as follows: before entering the subject score, there were 5 subjects initially, but after updating the course there are 6 subjects but and I am trying to add or remove the newly updated subject

Comment: so all subject in the result_template will have all subjects in result?

Comment: You can watch the video for better understanding: [link](https://ttprivatenew.s3.amazonaws.com/pulse/tikho900-gmail/attachments/20795407/TinyTake10-01-2023-09-01-04.mp4)

Comment: I will take a look when i get back

Comment: @hoangnv ... 1/2 ... The OP is advised to stay in the old thread ... here [_"How to merge two arrays containing objects, merge their fields and de-duplicate items"_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75056424/how-to-merge-two-arrays-containing-objects-merge-their-fields-and-de-duplicate) ... and edit / change it according to the questions / suggestions of the there given comments rather than opening a new thread with example data provided as a logging snapshot (which is worse then the clean data of the original question).

Comment: @hoangnv ... 2/2 ... Please consider removing either of the threads and editing the remaining one according to the already given suggestions and/or asked questions for any clarification on the OP's matter.